# How to change the dataframe from wide to long and add a week variable?

Tags: r, dplyr, transform

I want to transform the following data frame from wide to long with the `dplyr` library and consequently add a new column which gives the value of 0 to 6 ( those are the week numbers).

Basically, `ID1` should get the values of `x1.AI_mean, x2.AI_mean, x3.AI_mean, x4.AI_mean, x5.AI_mean, x6.AI_mean, x7.AI_mean` in a new column with a new name AI_mean. and so forth for `ID2, ID3, and ID4` and `Xn.MAD_mean, Xn.SD_mean, and Xn.ENMO_t_mean`. And finally a new variable `WEEK` that contains the values `0 to 6` per `IDn`

```
structure(list(PATIENT = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4"), X = c(720.5, 
720.5, 720.5, 720.5), x1.time = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), x1.AI_mean = c(0.490476892062554, 0.490476892062554, 
0.70756243831039, 0.500081418561785), x1.MAD_mean = c(0.00679103139766459, 
0.00679103139766459, 0.00954743428626949, 0.00710904629009617
), x1.SD_mean = c(0.0106151007507127, 0.0106151007507127, 0.015152755341205, 
0.0112303076216956), x1.ENMO_t_mean = c(0.0274584728800568, 0.0274584728800568, 
0.0103042219408169, 0.0312022382217336), x2.AI_mean = c(0.176041840541869, 
0.176041840541869, 0.592412808880571, 0.35677297296871), x2.MAD_mean = c(0.00219051379797853, 
0.00219051379797853, 0.00805673531422341, 0.00453736023712558
), x2.SD_mean = c(0.0042327545879746, 0.0042327545879746, 0.0140414178610565, 
0.00925877414143479), x2.ENMO_t_mean = c(0.0167368725509965, 
0.0167368725509965, 0.0227390281999353, 0.0155848050604389), 
    x3.AI_mean = c(0.196041545024115, 0.196041545024115, 0.655307840759778, 
    0.221302751464224), x3.MAD_mean = c(0.00265630445403654, 
    0.00265630445403654, 0.00874391858567126, 0.00312035180332525
    ), x3.SD_mean = c(0.00520681312926095, 0.00520681312926095, 
    0.0157667943293325, 0.00624832947258687), x3.ENMO_t_mean = c(0.0119919971714286, 
    0.0119919971714286, 0.0100238236393579, 0.00656607512069684
    ), x4.AI_mean = c(0.117134710729985, 0.117134710729985, 0.361142215576095, 
    0.152118386513676), x4.MAD_mean = c(0.00153368928913688, 
    0.00153368928913688, 0.00472008657879794, 0.00206572112752077
    ), x4.SD_mean = c(0.0030610465493998, 0.0030610465493998, 
    0.00871683182250033, 0.00425641902166748), x4.ENMO_t_mean = c(0.0206690781131853, 
    0.0206690781131853, 0.0164924536260057, 0.0322199920464069
    ), x5.AI_mean = c(0.152479968850333, 0.152479968850333, 0.372722877072248, 
    0.177229175029103), x5.MAD_mean = c(0.00218479624377481, 
    0.00218479624377481, 0.00487471442391749, 0.0024498723388947
    ), x5.SD_mean = c(0.00411993764019002, 0.00411993764019002, 
    0.00835039679052993, 0.00490289848155512), x5.ENMO_t_mean = c(0.0193947774446542, 
    0.0193947774446542, 0.0272692466077814, 0.0164903542931842
    ), x6.AI_mean = c(0.119878028436753, 0.119878028436753, 0.157829880732805, 
    0.1207450521664), x6.MAD_mean = c(0.00158146230736721, 0.00158146230736721, 
    0.0021877978464384, 0.00163733826134428), x6.SD_mean = c(0.00294818482781542, 
    0.00294818482781542, 0.0037086538389958, 0.00327129197883436
    ), x6.ENMO_t_mean = c(0.00917902093158174, 0.00917902093158174, 
    0.0162515614269202, 0.0208151667760968), x7.AI_mean = c(0.135059320114058, 
    0.135059320114058, 0.359440718946815, 0.130358911012721), 
    x7.MAD_mean = c(0.00195030841376017, 0.00195030841376017, 
    0.00404364526494212, 0.00182308928005729), x7.SD_mean = c(0.00370429514585471, 
    0.00370429514585471, 0.00767887188804178, 0.00351171698747009
    ), x7.ENMO_t_mean = c(0.021269549357265, 0.021269549357265, 
    0.0133371675149058, 0.0122713966971745)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

EDIT:

I now used the following code to get the long format table. However, how is it possible to add 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 to ID1 and 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 to ID2 and so forth in a new column in the same dataframe?

```
    NEW <- Mean_patient_per_7_weeks[,c(1,4,8,12,16,20,24,28)]
AI_mean <- NEW %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = ends_with("mean"),
    names_to = "AI_mean_month",
    values_to = "AI_mean",
    values_drop_na = TRUE
  )



structure(list(PATIENT = c("ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", 
"ID1", "ID1", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", 
"ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID4", "ID4", 
"ID4", "ID4", "ID4", "ID4", "ID4"), AI_mean_month = c("x1.AI_mean", 
"x2.AI_mean", "x3.AI_mean", "x4.AI_mean", "x5.AI_mean", "x6.AI_mean", 
"x7.AI_mean", "x1.AI_mean", "x2.AI_mean", "x3.AI_mean", "x4.AI_mean", 
"x5.AI_mean", "x6.AI_mean", "x7.AI_mean", "x1.AI_mean", "x2.AI_mean", 
"x3.AI_mean", "x4.AI_mean", "x5.AI_mean", "x6.AI_mean", "x7.AI_mean", 
"x1.AI_mean", "x2.AI_mean", "x3.AI_mean", "x4.AI_mean", "x5.AI_mean", 
"x6.AI_mean", "x7.AI_mean"), AI_mean = c(0.490476892062554, 0.176041840541869, 
0.196041545024115, 0.117134710729985, 0.152479968850333, 0.119878028436753, 
0.135059320114058, 0.490476892062554, 0.176041840541869, 0.196041545024115, 
0.117134710729985, 0.152479968850333, 0.119878028436753, 0.135059320114058, 
0.70756243831039, 0.592412808880571, 0.655307840759778, 0.361142215576095, 
0.372722877072248, 0.157829880732805, 0.359440718946815, 0.500081418561785, 
0.35677297296871, 0.221302751464224, 0.152118386513676, 0.177229175029103, 
0.1207450521664, 0.130358911012721)), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: What have you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: I used pivot_longer and dplyr

Comment: Let me more specific.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help, together with the instructions at the top of the page headed "Questions tagged [r]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(sjmisc)

A %>%
  pivot_longer(!c(PATIENT,X,x1.time), names_to = "Parameters", values_to = "AI_mean") %>%
  mutate(Week = parse_number(Parameters),
         MeanNames = case_when(grepl("AI", Parameters) ~ "AI_mean",
                               grepl("MAD", Parameters) ~ "MAD_mean",
                               grepl("SD", Parameters) ~ "SD_mean",
                               grepl("ENMO", Parameters) ~ "ENMO_t_mean")) %>%
  select(PATIENT,Week,AI_mean,MeanNames) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = MeanNames,values_from =AI_mean)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The table is now converted to a long format. However, the new variable column AI_mean should only contain values of x1.AI_mean, x2.AI_mean... first for ID1 then for ID2 and so forth. Then I want to create a new column with MAD_mean that should only contain values of x1.MAD_mean, x2.MAD_mean... first for ID1 and then for ID2 and so forth. And also for SD_mean and ENMO_t_mean. So 5  columns (variables): ID, AI_mean, MAD_mean, SD_mean and ENMO_t_mean

Comment: @Dataminer123 I have updated my answer. Does this satisfy your requirement?

Comment: Yes this is beautiful! Thank you very much @Deepansh Arora